# How do I make a regex to give me the name

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to get the display name result from a command it looks like the following truncated result.
It is shown as `name:`  below

```
$Group = gam info <Group Email> nousers noaliases

$Group
Group: <Group Email> 
  Group Settings:
    id: 020------v1
    name: email.admin@domain.com
    description:
    directMembersCount: 3
```

I am pretty sure I need to do this with Regex but I am not sure how to make the regex

And then once I have the regex I am not sure how I use it to get the name from `$group`

Comment: Does `gam` have an "output as CSV" ?

Comment: Not this command. I can't find a GAM command that will give me that display name field and put it to csv.

Comment: This might work `($group -notmatch 'Group Settings:').Trim() | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':' | Where-Object P1 -EQ name` you can also use that to have a proper object out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more concise (and more robust):

```
(gam info group $GroupEmail nousers noaliases) -match '^\s+name:' -replace '^.+: '
```

- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `^\s+name:` , applied via the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator, matches all lines in the output (in this case: one) that start with (`^`) one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`), followed by verbatim `name:`

  - Note: As PowerShell is in general, `-match` is case-*insensitive* by by default; for case-*sensitive* matching, use the `-cmatch` operator variant.
- The application of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator then effectively removes<sup>[1]</sup> everything from the start of the line `^` followed by one or more (`+`) characters, whatever they are (`.`), followed by verbatim `:` , returning the remainder of the line, i.e. the property *value*.

---

<sup>[1] By not supplying a replacement operand to `-replace` (the optional second RHS operand), whatever is matched is implicitly replaced by the *empty string*, and thereby effectively *removed*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful in the future if you need to get a proper object out of that command:

```
function Parse-GamInfo {
    (@($input) -notmatch 'Group Settings:').foreach{
        begin { $obj = @{} }
        process {
            $prop, $val = $_.Split(':').Trim()
            $obj[$prop] = $val
        }
        end {
            [pscustomobject]$obj
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pipe your command to this function to have an object that is easy to manipulate:

```
PS /> gam info <Group Email> nousers noaliases | Parse-GamInfo

Group         description name                   id          directMembersCount
-----         ----------- ----                   --          ------------------
<Group Email>             email.admin@domain.com 020------v1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is either

```
$GroupName = gam info group $GroupEmail nousers noaliases
$groupname = ($groupname -match 'Name:').Trim() | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':' | Select-Object P2
```

or

```
$GroupName = gam info group $GroupEmail nousers noaliases
$GroupName = $GroupName -match ('Name:')
$GroupName = $GroupName.trim().Split(' ')[1]
```

If someone can answer better then this please do.

one line seems to work

```
$GroupName = ((gam info group $GroupEmail nousers noaliases) -match ('Name:')).trim().Split(' ')[1]
```